# Automation of identification of real and false failures of Selenium tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

Our project has requirement of identifying real(product failures) and false(test issues) failures of Selenium tests so we can automate bug filing for real failures. If anyone has worked on such requirement, can you please guide me?

1. What approach should I take? Failure log analysis etc
2. Are there any supporting documents, videos to help me with this?
3. Are there any tools which will help for this?
4. Or any other more information

Comment: That's not exactly a small task. The main indicator is an assertion failure vs. a WebDriver exception. WebDriverException + stacktrace can sometimes mean "false failure", but that can also happen if a page breaks and elements cannot be located on the page, which would technically be a "real" failure. The best way to combat this problem is to write exception handling into your test cases to handle common "false-failure" scenarios and logically direct your test cases back to a functioning test path.

Comment: @TDHM what test framework are you using? Pytest is the one I would suggest.

Comment: try/catch all selenium actions... if exceptions are thrown, that action should fail and should be included in your report.  To decide which are "real" and "false" you need to understand your own test code and the web site's markup and scripting.  That definitely requires a human to examine each exception and decide whether it's a web site bug that should be written up or whether the test code needs fixin'.